# Facebook like counter decreases Google PageSpeed Insights Score?

Tags: facebook, google-pagespeed

I have included facebook like counter in my webpage but it decreases page speed percentage to less than 90 around 70. with following suggestion.How can i fix it ?

**Enable compression for the following resources to reduce their transfer size by 217KiB (72% reduction).
Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yj/r/kQcxVL8cgj4.js could save 217KiB (72% reduction).**

Answer (score 1):

You are right it is a problem that social sites don't concerns their widgets performance enough.

But you can solve it by loading the social icons or widgets after the page have loaded. Try take a look at this article http://hayageek.com/jquery-lazy-loading-scripts/. When you first load the scripts when the user starts to scroll the page, this will not harm you Page Speed score.